# open several instances of mail client in webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, webforms

I have a list of mail adresses, CCs, subjects, bodies,... and want to open each in a seperate mail client window. Right now I am just doing

```
form.Controls.Add(new LiteraclControl("<script>window.location.href = 'mailto:example@example.com?cc=&subject=ExampleSubject&body=ExampleBody'</script>"));
```

for each set of mail info I have. I tried putting each `window.location.href` in the same script block, seperated by `;`.

I know that this probably isn't the best practice, but I don't know how to do it in another way.

The Problem with this is that it only opens the last `mailto`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering, I now use `window.open('mailto:test@test.com?cc=&subject=testsubhect&body=testbody', '_top')`. Make sure to use the `'top'` parameter, otherwise it will open a blank tab for each time this function is called.